# RadDataBoundListBox event to command not fired

Tags: c#, telerik, command, mvvm-light

I have an issue with event to command binding with RadDataBoundListBox for Windows Phone 8.

I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PivotBackground}" DataContext="{Binding RecomandationViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    ..........
                <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox x:Name="DataBoundListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding RecommendedSongs}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" EmptyContent=" " DataVirtualizationMode="OnDemandAutomatic">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="DataRequested">
                           <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataRequestedCommand}"/>
                       </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemLoadingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <bitrimitives:BitBusyIndicator IsRunning="True" AnimationStyle="AnimationStyle9" Foreground="{StaticResource MyColor}" Content=""/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemLoadingTemplate>
                    </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
            </Grid>
```

And the view model code:

```
private RelayCommand _dataRequestedCommand;
    public RelayCommand DataRequestedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dataRequestedCommand == null)
            {
                _dataRequestedCommand = new RelayCommand(DataRequested, () => true);
            }
            return _dataRequestedCommand;
        }
    }
private void DataRequested()
    {
        int i = 4;
    }
```

The DataRequested method is never fired but if i subscribe to the DataRequested event of the  RadDataBoundListBox the method is fired. Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/raddataboundlistbox-features-datavirtualization-ondemandautomatic.html). Maybe it can help you.

The OnDemandAutomatic virtualization mode is a mode in which data items are automatically requested when the end-user approaches the end of the scrollable list. A possibility for displaying a specialized visual container indicating that a data request is being processed is available by using the ItemLoadingContent and ItemLoadingTemplate properties exposed by RadDataBoundListBox. A possible way of defining ItemLoadingTemplate is shown below:

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemLoadingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid MinHeight="14">
            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ellipseTranslate" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <SineEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
            <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="6" Height="6" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ellipseTranslate" X="0" />
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            </Ellipse>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemLoadingTemplate>
```

To use the OnDemandAutomatic virtualization mode simply set the DataVirtualizationMode property of the RadDataBoundListBox control to DataVirtualizationMode.OnDemandAutomatic. You will also need to handle the DataRequested event which will be fired when more data has to be loaded:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.radDataBoundListBox.DataVirtualizationMode = DataVirtualizationMode.OnDemandAutomatic;

    this.radDataBoundListBox.DataRequested += this.OnDataRequested;
}

private void OnDataRequested(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //TODO: download data items
}
```